# How to return most common name from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, fuzzy

I am working on fuzzy matching two dataframes using fuzzywuzzy. I set a cutoff score of 75, using process.extractOne to get the highest match.

Whenever a match is not made the value for that row is 'None'.

How do I replace 'None' with the most common name?

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

df1['Matched_Nickname_and_Score'] = df1['FNAME'].apply(lambda x: 
process.extractOne(x, df2['NICKNAME'].tolist(), score_cutoff = 75))
```

I have a way of finding the max value for each row, but not sure where to go from here

```
maxValuesObj = df1.max(axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that might help:

```
df1['Matched_Nickname_and_Score'] = df1['Matched_Nickname_and_Score'].fillna(value=df1.FNAME.mode().values[0])
```

`df1.FNAME.mode().values[0]` will get the most common name from the column *FNAME* of the *df1* dataframe. You just need to use *fillna* with that value and you'll get what you are looking for.